# What would be the best way to bypass the same origin policy if I'm using an iFrame that displays the website of a user inputted URL?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I'm working on a website that can allow the user to visit websites blocked by their school/employer by means of an iframe. The user is meant to input a URL which the iframe then displays, but the same origin policy prevents many sites from being accessed. How would I go about getting around this? I've already read a lot of stackoverflow posts about bypassing the same origin policy but I couldn't figure out how to implement those methods, as I'm extremely new to HTML and Javascript. My code is as follows:

```html
<form>
  URL: 
  <input type="text" id="url" name="url" value=""><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit()" value="Search" />

  <script>
    function formSubmit() {
    var urle = document.getElementById("url").value;
   document.getElementById("iframe1").src =
              urle;  
}
  </script>
  
<iframe  id="iframe1" scrolling="yes" height="900" width ="900" src=""></iframe>
</form>
```

I would greatly appreciate an answer as I've been trying to solve this issue for a while now. Thanks.

Comment: How have these sites been blocked ? If they are blocked on network level there is not much you can do with CORS settings

Comment: The same-origin policy doesn't apply to iframes, except that it prevents the two pages from accessing each other's contents. But you can load a page from any domain into an iframe, unless the destination page explicitly blocks use in iframes.

Comment: The same-origin policy is about AJAX, not iframes.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean `X-Frame-Options`. It's a security matter and you can not bypass it. The only option you have is to open an popup window instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function formSubmit() {
      var urle = document.getElementById("url").value,
          win = window.open(urle, "preview",'height=200, width=150');
          if(window.focus) win.focus();
      }
</script>

<form>
  URL: 
  <input type="text" id="url" name="url" value=""><br />
  <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit()" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Couple issues here.

1. Browser -- security headers
2. Network -- Website blocked

At the browser level, X-Frame-Options is the security header in the way of your cool window to the web app.

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate
>   whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a
>   `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>` . Sites can use this **to avoid**
>   **clickjacking attacks**, by ensuring that their content is not embedded
>   into other sites.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

What is meant by attack vectors, let's say your bank website allowed iframes and you logged in recently. Someone could put your bank in an iframe and trick you into thinking you were on the main site. Maybe there was a button over some other important button on said bank site and some UI was overlaid over the iframe to bait a particular behavior. When the user went to click on the overlaid item, the item disappeared and the click went to the bank iframe. Now someone has tricked the user into performing an unintended action.

This is called click jacking.

That's dangerous. And this is a contrived silly example. In the wild it becomes much more sophisticated than this, particularly for high profile websites.

--

Way to get around this *for sites outside of your control* is to use a proxy, where a user posts a url to a server, that then resolves the URL, downloads the content and sends the content back to the client. This escapes the browser security sandbox.

Keep in mind though, services like this pose a danger. This means completely trusting the server to not do something nefarious like inject content or read login credentials.

There are a few proxy services which are free. Not willing to list them because most are riddled with adware.

So what to do? How is everyone else getting around this? Likely reading posts that have to do with someone trying to iframe a domain they themselves control, like a subdomain foo.DomainA.com. If you have access to the server that delivers the page you want to iframe, security headers can be adjusted to whitelist a domain, so Domain A can iframe to Domain B. Looks something like:

```
X-Frame-Options: allow-from https://example.com/
```

However most domains have this set to:

```
X-Frame-Options: deny
```

--

Another option is to have all of your users use a browser plugin to strip security headers like X-Frame-Options. If you search 'chrome plugin modify headers iframe' quite a few come up.

However remember this just solves the browser security sandbox issue. If a site URL is blocked by admins at the school or work then you will need to use a proxy to download the content for you.

Alternatively yourself and potential users could use TOR to circumvent network level restrictions, highly recommend reading the docs, it's available here:
https://www.torproject.org/